# Javascript Validation between two input fields without clicking on save button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate Cost and Retail i.e., cost should not be greater than retail.
This is the Input for Cost:

```
 <label>Cost* : </label>
 <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" size="3" required  maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"></td></tr>
```

This is the input of Retail:

```
<label>Retail* : </label>
<input type="text" id="retail_price" name="retail_price" size="3" required  maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
function itemChange(selectObject){
document.getElementById("cost").value = cost;
document.getElementById("retail_price").value = retail;
if (cost >= retail)
    {
         return confirm("Retail Cannot be less or equal to Cost");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        true;
    }
}
```

My Javascript validation of comparing two numbers is working but on a submit button click, I want to Call the Validation function after the user Enters Cost and Retail and hovers anywhere outside the inputs.

It should validate automatically after cost and retail are entered. How and where should I call my validation function?

Comment: Post your JS please

Comment: [Blur Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) is may be what u are looking for.. and calling your validation.

Comment: I am using GetElementById for assigning cost and retail values to newcp and newrp variables.if (parseInt(newcp) >= parseInt(newrp))
    {
         return confirm("Retail Cannot be less or equal to Cost");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        true;
    }

Comment: If your JS is all you wrote then it got four mistakes: 1st is that you declare a variable that is never used. 2nd in line 2 and 3 you try to safe the values but you mistaken the left/right -hand side assignment expression. The left variable is the variable where the value of the right variable goes to. In your case that means the value of cost for example goes to the value of the HTMLNode. 3rd is the `return false` will never happen  because you return something before in the same block. the 4th is the expression `true` this is useless if you don't put a `return` before for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fields = [$('#cost'), $('#retail_price')];
fields.forEach((field)=>{
    field.addEventListener('blur', _ => {
         if (fields.every(field => field.value !== "")){
              YOUR CHECK FUNCTION!
         }
    })
})
```

You can do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `blur` event on both the `input`s thus your code will execute whenever one of the buttons loses focus :

```js
// select the inputs globally so we can reference them later in the code
const cost = document.getElementById("cost"),
  retail = document.getElementById("retail_price");

// loop through the two inputs and assign a "blur" event listener
[cost, retail].forEach(i =>
  // assign the listener function
  i.addEventListener("blur", () =>
    console.log(
      // the "+" signs casts the values to integers
      +cost.value >= +retail.value
        ? "Retail Cannot be less or equal to Cost"
        : "The inputs are ok!"
    )
  )
);
```

```html
<label>Cost* : </label>
<input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" size="3" required maxlength="5" autocomplete="off">
<label>Retail* : </label>
<input type="text" id="retail_price" name="retail_price" size="3" required maxlength="5" autocomplete="off">
```